# Получаю пустой ответ crawler node.js?

Tags: node.js, парсер

Пробую вот так:

```js
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");

var myCrawler = new Crawler("www.example.com");
        myCrawler.initialPath = "/archive";
        //myCrawler.initialPort = 8080;
        //myCrawler.initialProtocol = "https";
        myCrawler.interval = 10000; // Ten seconds
        myCrawler.maxConcurrency = 1;
        myCrawler.maxDepth = 1; // Only first page is fetched (with linked CSS & images)

myCrawler.on("fetchcomplete", function(queueItem, responseBuffer, response) {
    console.log("Я только что получил %s (%d bytes)", queueItem.url, responseBuffer.length);
    console.log("Это был ресурс типа %s", response.headers['content-type']);

    // Do something with the data in responseBuffer
    callback(responseBuffer);
});

myCrawler.start();
```

Запускаю из папки с проектом, вот так: `node index.js`
После чего приходит пустая строка. Что я делаю не так? 
Брал этот пример из [репозитория библиотеки](https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler).